# Hiding statusbar using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

How can we hide the statusbar of a current page using javascript.I used window.statusbar.visible = false but its not working.Please give me a solution

regards

Arun

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can hide it for an already opened window : it's not an element of the page, but an element of the browser's user interface -- which means it's outside of your concern.

*(Even if you can open a new window that doesn't have a status-bar ;; which might not be liked that much by some users, btw)*

Comment: +1 for pointing out that this sort of interface modification is *really annoying*. I **like** my status bar, and I don't want some website getting rid of it.

Comment: Even `window.open` features don't typically let you remove the status bar any more. And bleedin' good thing too.

Answer (score 2):

Status bars are something people expect to see in every browser window. By not hiding it, you give users the first sense of safety that the content they see is still being served within a browser. You may be trying to simulate a desktop application experience on the web. But once you code for the web, you have to happily accept the standard elements that come with it.

Technically, no, you cannot hide the status bar after opening the window.

Comment: Actually, in previous versions of Safari, it defaulted to not showing the status bar.

Comment: When people know that their browser is capable of hiding the status bar, they don't panic. But it's not the case in browsers that default to showing the status bar.